# three.js Collada model animation too fast

Tags: animation, three.js, collada

Based on `webgl_loader_collada` and `webgl_loader_collada_skinning`, 
I tried to load my own basic collada simple model. 
But the result is : the animation is too fast.

When I load the example collada models (avatar and monster), the speed is normal and their animation is also on 250 frames or less. 
So i don't know what is wrong with my own model.

[Here is my project](http://www.lesmaudits.org/three/)

On `page.html` you can see the result and if you want all the files, you can download `pack.7z`.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: having a quick look I see that `monster.geometry.animation.length` is `0.1`. This does not seem correct.

Comment: Yes you're right... How can i change that please ?